# Can android handlemessage be reentered?

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, android-handler

I have a handler that updates UI periodically, from timer.
Sometimes updating may take longer than timer interval. What would happen in this case? Does Android monitor `handlemessage` to make sure it finished its work, or should I do it myself? Probably a silly question, but didn't find any reference to it after a long googling.

EDIT:

I am asking because I have `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, and elements from it are removed inside a method called from `handlemessage`. It's the only place where they are removed, and yet sometimes I can see that 2 elements are removed instead of one. Like `handlemessage` was re-entered. 
If, according to @Gabe it is impossible, what other explanation could be there?

Comment: no it can't you have to do it yourself by your logic.

Comment: any reference confirming this? just want to know what link I have missed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All messages to a handler occur on the same thread.  So its impossible to have re-entrant instances unless you're calling handler.handleMessage directly.  handlers are part of an event loop-  events are sent to the Looper object, and when the thread finishes each event it gets the next event from the Looper (in this case an event being a handler message) and process it in FIFO order.

Answer (score 2):

The messages sent to a `Handler` are queued and processed in order, but that does not mean that they are processed at an even pace. Consider this code:

```
myHandler.postDelayed(thisRunnableWillTakeTenSeconds, 1000);
myHandler.postDelayed(anotherRunnable, 2000);
```

The second `Runnable` will execute right after the first one, not 1 second later, because it will already be overdue when the first one completes.